# Golang sort two slices

Tags: go

I have two integer slices, the elements are not necessarily unique.

```
nums1 := [1,3,2,4]
nums2 := [12,47,23,1]
```

I wanted to sort `nums1` and swap the elements in `num2` accordingly, i.e:

```
nums1 -> [1,2,3,4]
nums2 -> [12,23,47,1]
```

If I were to do the sorting myself, I can obviously swap the `nums2` elements whenever I swap the `nums1` ones. I wonder if it is possible to achieve it without having writing the sort myself or depending on external libraries (using sort package is obviously okay).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sort](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) package with [slice](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Slice) function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    nums1 := []int{1, 3, 2, 4}
    nums2 := []int{12, 47, 23, 1}

    sort.Slice(nums1, func(i, j int) bool {
        // Check for sorting
        cond := nums1[i] < nums1[j]
        if cond {
            nums2[i], nums2[j] = nums2[j], nums2[i]
        }
        return cond
    })

    fmt.Println("nums1:", nums1)
    fmt.Println("nums2:", nums2)
}
```

Comment: don't ask me why, but your solutions works until len(slice) <=12.


Here a demo with 13 elements https://go.dev/play/p/xCbugUeDa43

Answer (score -2):

Here's an O(N) solution. The only overhead is the temp array copy back.

```
func sortSpecial(nums1 []int, nums2 []int) {
    nums3 := make([]int, len(nums1))
    for i:= 0; i < len(nums1); i++ {
        nums3[i] = nums2[nums1[i]-1]
    }
    copy(nums2,nums3)
}
```